# Manual entries in google spreadsheet do not match when the data gets updated

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I have a google spreadsheet which have some columns of data written through a python script. At the end of the last data column I have added three more columns manually and data for those three columns would be entered manually. Python script would run daily, thus updating the data in the spreadsheet. My issue is whenever I run the script to update the data, the data in the last three manual columns gets jumbled. This is because the order of the data returned by the sql query from the script is different everytime. We can use order by to keep the order same but if new rows are added or the existing rows are deleted from the db then this would also not work.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [related thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/ntzSlDUZjHw), I think it's an expected behavior because the imported data is dynamic and the data you are adding are static.

> The idea is that you don't add any columns to the Sheet that receives the imported data as this data is dynamic.
>
> You need to create a new Sheet and select the data from the Sheet that has the imported data.
>
> The Notes Sheet will need you to select the imported data by the order number in this case. The other columns of data will then be extracted from the ImportedData Sheet using the =vlookup() function and displayed and then you would enter the required note for that record.

You may check the link above for more information.